# how should std::clamp be used with clang++ 4

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++

std::clamp was supposed to work in c++17 but when used with clang++ version 4.0 with `std=c++1z` flag and including `<algorithm>` header it complains `no member named clamp in namespace 'std'`

Comment: [Works for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/M8hjsFsGzyBPO5Xu). Did you say `-stdlib=libc++`?

Comment: `clamp` isn't implemented by compiler but by standard library, so you need to use one that provides it, i.e. @up is probably right about his suggestion.